# "The member is not recognized or is not accessible" when using custom UserControl from different assembly

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, .net-assembly

I have solution with one wpf application assembly `MyApp` and one .NET class library assembly `CutomUC`. The `CustomUC` class library is supposed to hold all of my custom user controls which are used from wpf application.

I have written simple `ImageButton` `UserControl`. Whenever I set some dependency property of my custom control from wpf application, designer wont render, and I get the following warning (or error, it is shown as blue underline in xaml):

```
The member "[member name]" is not recognized or is not accessible
```

However, application builds and runs just fine.

Here is my custom `UserControl`, from `CustomUC` assembly:

```
public partial class ImageButton : UserControl
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(ImageButton), new UIPropertyMetadata(OnArrangementChanged));
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Image", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(ImageButton), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageMarginProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ImageMargin", typeof(string), typeof(ImageButton), new UIPropertyMetadata("0, 0, 0, 0"));
        public static readonly DependencyProperty OrientationProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Orientation", typeof(Orientation), typeof(ImageButton), new UIPropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnArrangementChanged)));

    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }
    public ImageSource Image
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(ImageProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ImageProperty, value); }
    }
    public string ImageMargin
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(ImageMarginProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ImageMarginProperty, value); }
    }
    public Orientation Orientation
    {
        get { return (Orientation)GetValue(OrientationProperty); }
        set { SetValue(OrientationProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void OnArrangementChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var myUserControl = sender as ImageButton;
        myUserControl.RearangeElements();
    }

    public ImageButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        RearangeElements();
    }

    private void RearangeElements()
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Text))
        {
            Grid.SetRow(ButtonImage, 0);
            Grid.SetColumn(ButtonImage, 0);
            Grid.SetRowSpan(ButtonImage, 2);
            Grid.SetColumnSpan(ButtonImage, 2);
        }
        else if (this.Orientation == Orientation.Horizontal)
        {
            Grid.SetColumnSpan(ButtonImage, 1);
            Grid.SetColumnSpan(ButtonTextBlock, 1);
            Grid.SetRowSpan(ButtonTextBlock, 2);
            Grid.SetRowSpan(ButtonImage, 2);
            Grid.SetColumn(ButtonImage, 0);
            Grid.SetColumn(ButtonTextBlock, 1);
            Grid.SetRow(ButtonImage, 0);
            Grid.SetRow(ButtonTextBlock, 0);
        }
        else if (this.Orientation == Orientation.Vertical)
        {
            Grid.SetColumnSpan(ButtonTextBlock, 2);
            Grid.SetColumnSpan(ButtonImage, 2);
            Grid.SetRowSpan(ButtonTextBlock, 1);
            Grid.SetRowSpan(ButtonImage, 1);
            Grid.SetRow(ButtonImage, 0);
            Grid.SetRow(ButtonTextBlock, 1);
            Grid.SetColumn(ButtonImage, 0);
            Grid.SetColumn(ButtonTextBlock, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is `ImageButton.xaml`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="CustomUC.UserControls.ImageButton"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CustomUC.UserControls"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
             Name="ImageButton"
             Background="Transparent"
             BorderBrush="Transparent"
             BorderThickness="0">
    <Button Name="ButtonElement"
        Height="{Binding ElementName=ImageButton, Path=Height}"
        Width="{Binding ElementName=ImageButton, Path=Width}">
        <Button.Content>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Name="ButtonImage" Source="{Binding ElementName=ImageButton, Path=Image}" Margin="{Binding ElementName=ImageButton, Path=ImageMargin}"/>
                <TextBlock Name="ButtonTextBlock" Text="{Binding ElementName=ImageButton, Path=Text}" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
        </Button.Content>
    </Button>
</UserControl>
```

And here is `MainWindow.xaml` from `MyApp` assembly:

```
<Window x:Class="MyApp.View.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:resx="clr-namespace:MyApp.localization"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp.View"
        xmlns:customuc="clr-namespace:CustomUC.UserControls;assembly=CustomUC"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="720" Width="1280">
    <Grid>
        <customuc:ImageButton Width="100" Height="100" Text="Hello!" Image="/MyApp;component/Assets/352456 - drive file insert.ico" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="840,103,332,486"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

`Text`, `Image` and `Orientation` all show the same warning. I want to be able to access dependency properties as if the control was in the same assembly (I want designer to render correctly, and autocomplete feature). Is that possible, am I missing something?

Comment: After making necessary changes you have to build the project then only xaml will determine dependency properties. Can you try it and let me know?

Comment: I tried cleaning, building, and rebuilding the who solution multiple times. No success. Or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: Is the casing used in your MainWindow.xaml correct? You have xmlns:customuc="clr-namespace:customuc.UserControls;assembly=CustomUC", but the user control is defined in CustomUC.UserControls (not customuc.UserControls).

Comment: @Eric true, but that was only an error on question writing side, I was switching true namespaces for generic ones, I checked the original file, it as well and good in there, I have edited the question to correct my mistake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out everything was fine. Once I got back to the computer, turned it and VS on everything was working as expected. My best guess would be that VS didn't load something that was needed yesterday.

If you are having the same problem, try restarting your VS.

Comment: Why down-vote? I genuinely had a problem I described, I tried many xaml variations alongside building cleaning and rebuilding solution, and nothing helped, I lost 3-4 hours trying to solve this problem, and at the end of my workday I decided to seek help. Next day, it was working as expected. I don't understand the down-vote on question or the answer, it is not like it is a green field/blue sky problem, or best option recommendation.

Comment: Worked for me. Sometimes VS just needs a reset! Thanks for the answer it saved me a bunch of time.